# My PyCharm menubar went missing on macOS, how do I get a menu bar again?

Tags: macos, user-interface, pycharm

The main menu bar has gone missing for the PyCharm app on macOS. How do I get a menu bar again so I can continue sipping coffee and writing code?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Java VM (JVM) property, `apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar` in one of several ways. The first way is the way prescribed by IntelliJ: add the property to the `idea.vmoptions` file in the `~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm<version>` directory. Simply make sure that the following line is contained in the aforementioned file:

```
-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
```

If the file does not exist yet, first copy the default file from `/Applications/<product.app>/Contents/bin`.

Another method is to set the property in the `Info.plist` contained within the PyCharm app bundle. WARNING: this will invalidate the app bundle signature! For instance, if your PyCharm app is installed to `/Applications`, you can run this python script to make the change:

```
import plistlib

PATH_TO_INFO_PLIST = "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/Info.plist"

info_plist_data = plistlib.readPlist(PATH_TO_INFO_PLIST)

jvm_options = info_plist_data.get("JVMOptions", dict())

jvm_properties = jvm_options.get("Properties", dict())

jvm_properties.update({
    "apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar": True
})

jvm_options.update({
    "Properties": jvm_properties
})

info_plist_data.update({
    "JVMOptions": jvm_options
})

plistlib.writePlist(info_plist_data, PATH_TO_INFO_PLIST)
```